# Unknown command 'import-cypher', when trying to import into Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j 3.1.1 and I followed this to download and install neo4j-shell-tools:
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/tree/3.1 but when I do this in my shell:

```
`Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands. Please note that neo4j-shell is deprecated and to be replaced by cypher-shell.
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ help
Available commands: alias begin call cd commit create cypher dbinfo drop dump env explain export foreach gsh help index jsh load ls man match merge mknode mkrel mv optional paths planner profile pwd return rm rmnode rmrel rollback runtime schema set start trav unwind using with
Use man <command> for info about each command.
Please note that neo4j-shell is deprecated and to be replaced by cypher-shell.
neo4j-sh (?)$ import-cypher
Unknown command 'import-cypher'`
```

I can't see what is the problem

any suggestions on how to solve this, what have I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you ever able to get this problem figured out?